# Why does a get_squared_range object appear?

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

Just loading in an excel file using openpyxl.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
filename = 'test.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename, use_iterators=True)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

print(ws['A1'].value)
>>> <generator object get_squared_range at 0x102c0b5a0>
```

[The documentation suggests](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.iter_worksheet.IterableWorksheet.get_squared_range) an get_squared_range object is generated for blank cells, but the cell is not empty.

Comment: Have you tried `print(ws['A1'].value)`

Comment: object doesn't have that attribute. Did an inspect and nothing screamed like it'd be a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with the `use_iterators=True` parameter you pass to the `load_workbook()` function.

Try without it -

```
wb = load_workbook(filename)
```